# How can i get xml node value from string

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get *XML* values from the following *XML* node:

```
<StockQuotes>
  <Stock>
    <Symbol>LLOY.L</Symbol>
    <Last>76.27</Last>
    <Date>8/29/2014</Date>
  </Stock>
</StockQuotes>
```

Here is my code:

```
XmlDocument quoteXML = new XmlDocument();

string strData = myXMLfile;
quoteXML.LoadXml(strData);
XmlNode nodes = quoteXML.SelectSingleNode("StockQuotes/Stock/Last/Date");
string strPrice = nodes["Last"].InnerText;
string strDate = nodes["Date"].InnerText;

Response.Write( strPrice + strDate );
```

I am getting the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

when I write the whole string `strData` to the view I get all of the *XML* so I know the file is valid.

Comment: What programming language is this? Add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Please be more relevant and as @PolymorphicPotato said, tell us what language/plateform are you in!

Comment: Sorry, this is in C# webforms

Comment: Error raised is due to an object being used before it has been instantiated. Do verify your objects on debugging mode!

Comment: Nadeem, are you guessing mate. If you read the post properly it tells you that the XML can be written to the view in full. If you don't have a resolution, why are you replying?

Answer (score 0):

**SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM:**

`quoteXML.SelectSingleNode("StockQuotes/Stock/Last/Date");` [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx) call will return representation of `<Date>8/29/2014</Date>`,

But you try to [access subnodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sss31aas(v=vs.110).aspx) `["Last"]` and `["Date"]`, that are not child nodes of `<Date>8/29/2014</Date>` and taking into account that indexer returns:

> The first XmlElement that matches the specified name. It returns a
>   null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if there is no match.

`nodes["Last"]` and `nodes["Base"]` will be both `null`, resulting in [`NullReferenceException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) on `.InnerText` property access.

**SOLUTION:**

Use

```
XmlNode nodes = quoteXML.SelectSingleNode("StockQuotes/Stock");
```

to access `Stock` node instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with special charchters in the XML feed. I have resolved the issue and used:

```
'string strData = WebService.GetDate(); // returns xml as string
            string decoded = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(strData); quoteXML.LoadXml(decoded); 

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(decoded);
            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/StockQuotes/Stock");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                strQuote = xn["Last"].InnerText;
            }'
```